# Select all child elements from given layer XML

Tags: css, xml, css-selectors

I want to select all child elements that belong to one layer in the XML hierarchy, beginning with a given element. So if the XML structure looks like this:

```
  <teststep id="1">
    <description>Teststep 1</description>      
    <call-action id="2">
      <parameters>
        <parameter key="starttime" />
        <parameter key="duration" />
      </parameters>
      <results>
        <store-result key="" destination=""/>
      </results>
    </call-action>
    <call-action id="3">
      <parameters>
        <parameter key="starttime" />
        <parameter key="duration" />
      </parameters>
      <results>
        <store-result key="" destination=""/>
      </results>
    </call-action>
  </teststep>
```

I would like to select all child elements from the first level, something like this:

```
teststep > first child elements in the hierarchy { ... }
```

and the elements that are affected should only be **description** and the 2 **call-action** elements.

and the same for the second layer (affected elements: **parameters**) and so on.

Does somebody have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: `teststep > *` would mean anything that is a direct descendant of teststep

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you looking for two separate CSS rules, one for description, call-action and one for parameters, or a single rule targeting the parameters descendants of teststep?

Comment: @BoltClock I am looking for 2 separate rules.

Comment: I should also point out that styles cascade so even though `teststep > *` is for direct descendants, the styles will also cascade down to any children, unless overwritten by another style like `teststep > * > *` - [example](https://jsfiddle.net/qrgLzyq7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `description` and `call-action` elements with

```
teststep > *
```

and the `parameters` elements with, assuming you still want to select them relative to this particular `teststep`,

```
teststep > call-action > parameters
```

(If you only want to select them relative to their parent `call-action`, no matter what the `call-action`'s parent is, leave out the `teststep >`.)